# Canvas coordinates in "for" loop, Java

Tags: java, calendar

I have a beginners question. I cant for the life of it conceptually wrap my head around this piece of code in the if statement: 5*i+j>= 7

This is part of a "calendar program" exercise in the Art and Science of Java book. My main problem was how to set the first date of the month during a weekday, thus pushing all the days of the month in a calendar several days over.

I looked up the answer, but still do not get it, the solution was to simply put 5*i+j>= 7 in my if statement and it works, but how?
Changing i or j was my initial idea, but I cant figure out how adding them moves the calendar days correctly to the right without moving entire weeks.

I removed the code for the actual calendar squares while trying to decompose the problem to make it leaner.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class RandomCodeTesting extends GraphicsProgram{

    private static final int DAYS_IN_MONTH = 31;
    private static final int DAY_MONTH_STARTS =5;

    public void run() {
        int d = 1;  
        for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<7; j++) {
                int x= j*45;
                int y= i*15;
                if (5*i+j>= 7 && d <= 31) {
                    add(new GLabel(""+d), x, y);
                    d++;
                }       
            }   
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition should really be `DAY_MONTH_STARTS * i + j >= 7`.

This is basically determining whether to put a `GLabel` on the coordinates<sup>1</sup> `(j, i)`.

Let's consider the case of `DAY_MONTH_STARTS` equals 5. What this means is that the coordinates `(0, 1)` and `(1, 1)` should not have a `GLabel`, leaving the first row of the calendar to have 5 `GLabel`s while all the rows in the middle have 7 `GLabel`s.

In general, any coordinates with the x value less than `(7 - DAY_MONTH_STARTS)` and the y value being 1 should not have a `GLabel`.

This means that you can rewrite the condition as so:

```
if(!(j < (7 - DAY_MONTH_STARTS) && i == 1) && d <= DAYS_IN_MONTH) {
    add(new GLabel(""+d), x, y);
    d++;
}
```

`DAY_MONTH_STARTS * i + j >= 7` is really just a math trick that does the same thing.

Comment: Good Answer. And a good example why app developers should generally *not* use clever “math trick“ code. I would choose to use the longer, more self-documenting code shown here in this Answer rather than the shorter code seen in the Question.